# Does OpenAPI allow a $ref to a _specific_ enum value?

Tags: jsonschema, openapi

Let's say in my OpenAPI v3 description, I have the following `/componenets/schemas` entry (using YAML) format:

```
WidgetTypes:
  type: string
  enum:
    - WIDGET_A
    - WIDGET_B
    - WIDGET_C
```

The `WidgetTypes` schema is thus a named (i.e. value `$ref`) enum 'class'. In various other places in the API spec, we can now refer to these enum values, e.g. perhaps there's an API path for which one of the path elements must come from the `WidgetTypes` set.

Now, I have also some additional schemas (i.e. object data models), and there might be a case where a *specific* `WidgetType` value is a *constant* for that object type. An example:

```
MySpecificWidgetA:
  type: object
  properties:
    someField1:
      type: string
    someField2:
      type: number
    widgetType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - WIDGET_A
```

This feels like the naïve way to accomplish this, since now `MySpecificWidgetA`'s `widgetType` field is a string that comes from the set of possible `WidgetType`'s, **but there's no actual reference to `WidgetType` enforcing this**.
In spirit, what I'd like to assert is that `MySpecificWidgetA.widgetType` is a *specific value* from the `WidgetType` enum schema (in this case `WIDGET_A`).
Using just `$ref: '#/components/schemas/WidgetType'` passes validation, but doesn't accomplish what I want: it states `widgetType` is simply a value coming from that set ... I want it to be a *restricted* value from that set (i.e. a constant).

I've tried experimenting with `$ref` a few other ways for the value of `widgetType`, including (without success):

```
$ref: '#/components/schemas/WidgetType/WIDGET_A'
```

```
$ref: '#/components/schemas/WidgetType/enum/WIDGET_A'
```

```
$ref: '#/components/schemas/WidgetType/enum/0'
```

(the last one being not very useful, but just testing out the exact JSON Pointer format that `$ref` uses.)

None of these attempts above pass the OpenAPI v3 validation ... does anyone know if it's possible to reference (via `$ref` or some other mechanism) a *specific value* from a defined enum schema element?

Comment: I don't think this was a duplicate.  It's very similar, but this question is worded to be more about the capability of the `$ref` keyword than enums directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not allowed by JSON Schema.  `$ref` is only allowed to resolved to other schema objects, not to individual data points.